# Socket timeout caught as OSError

Tags: python, sockets, ping

I have some code like so:

```
try:
    socket.create_connection((fqdn, 80), timeout=TIMEOUT).close()
except socket.timeout as e:
    print('Error timeout: %s' % e)
except OSError as e:
    print('Error other: %s' % e)
```

When running on my local machine, with a setup that would generate a timeout, I have the expected output `Error timeout: timed out` to the console.

When the same code is run in our pre-prod environment, the output is `Error other: timed out` which means that an error has been thrown that is not a `socket.timeout` but has the message `timed out`.

What is hapenning here?

PS. I cannot easily release a code update to the pre-prod environment to add more logs...

[edit] Running on Python 3.4.2

Comment: It would be a lot more useful to have an actual exception stack traceback. Which version of python is this?

Comment: Python 3.4.2. Yes it would indeed, unfortunately I don't have one.

Comment: Here is a stacktrace example:
`File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host`

Comment: James, the above example is with Python 3.7.3